# I need detect the approximate location of QR code in scanned image (PDF converted to PNG)

Tags: pdf, image-processing, imagemagick, qr-code

I have many scanned document in PDF.

I use ImageMagick with Ghostscript to convert PDF to PNG in big density. I use `convert -density 288 2.pdf 2.png`. After that I read the pixels with PHP and find where is QR code and decode it. Because image is very big (~ 2500px), it's need very much RAM. I want, before I read pixels with PHP,  to crop the image with ImageMagick and leave only that part with the QR code.

Can I **detect the approximate location of QR code** with ImageMagick, crop and leave only that part ?

[image: converted png]

[Sample PDF](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59611541/2.pdf)

[Converted PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdLiE.png)

Comment: Can you please give additional hints about the locations and other specifics of your QR codes? For example: Are they always the same size and the same QR version? Is their placement always on the right half of the page? Anything that may make the task more easy to accomplish for the general case... (it is rather easy to accomplish for the posted example).

Comment: I needn't decode it, but need to leave only part with qr code, not exactly qr code, but do it smaller like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59611541/2_crop.png
I don't know where placement will be, and size of image and qr code will be different.

Comment: A general hint: Your sample PDF page essentially only contains one image. If all (or at least many) of your documents are like this, you should *extract* these images instead of rendering the PDF as a new image. They are the best quality you can get.

Comment: @mkl: What program i will use?

Comment: *What program i will use* - Maybe @KurtPfeifle or others can help here. I'm more into programming PDF processing tools, I don't know existing tools that good.

Comment: The best command line tool to extract images from a PDF is `pdfimages`. But please use a very recent version of the Poppler fork of that tool, not from the XPDF parent code base. Because this will let you run `pdfimages -ccitt the.pdf prefix-`, and your images will be extracted with the original CCITT compression. *(Since you probably do not have a CCITT processing image processing application, you should use  `pdfimages -png the.pdf prefix-` to output lossless PNG images.)*

Comment: Thank you, I use MacOS, and will try install pdfimages with homebrew.

Comment: Now, I trying to do my work with -morphology Erode/Dilate

Comment: @AshotKhanamiryan: Which version does Homebrew give you (`pdfimages -v`)? Mine is `0.32.0`, but it is from MacPorts, not Homebrew...

Comment: mine is 0.29.0 , it's from poppler (brew install poppler)

Answer (score 7):

**Further Update**

I see your discussion with Kurt about better extraction of the image from the PDF in the first place, and his recommendation was to use `pdfimages`. I just wanted to add that you won't find that if you do `brew search pdfimages`, but you actually need to use

```
brew install poppler
```

and then you get the `pdfimages` executable.

**Updated Answer**

If you change the tile size to 100x100 on the crop command and run this for the second PDF you supplied:

```
convert -density 288 pdf2.pdf -crop 100x100 tile%04d.png
```

and then use the same entropy analysis command

```
convert -format "%[entropy]:%X%Y:%f\n" tile*.png info: | sort -n
...
...
0.84432:+600+3100:tile0750.png
0.846019:+600+2800:tile0678.png
0.980938:+700+400:tile0103.png
0.984906:+700+500:tile0127.png
0.988808:+600+400:tile0102.png
0.998365:+600+500:tile0126.png
```

The last 4 listed tiles are

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Likewise for the other PDF file you supplied, you get

```
0.863498:+1900+500:tile0139.png
0.954581:+2000+500:tile0140.png
0.974077:+1900+600:tile0163.png
0.97671:+2000+600:tile0164.png
```

which means these tiles

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would think that should help you pretty much approximately locate the QR code.

**Original Answer**

This is not all that scientific, but it may help you get started. The key, I think, is the entropy of the various areas of the image. The QR code has a lot of information encoded in a small area so it should have high entropy. So, I use ImageMagick to split the image into square 400x400 tiles like this:

```
convert image.png -crop 400x400 tile%03d.png
```

which gives me 54 tiles. Then I calculate the entropy of each of the tiles and sort them by increasing entropy, also outputting their offsets from the top left of the frame, and their name, like this:

```
convert -format "%[entropy]:%X%Y:%f\n" tile*.png info: | sort -n

0.00408949:+1200+2800:tile045.png
0.00473755:+1600+2800:tile046.png
0.00944815:+800+2800:tile044.png
0.0142171:+1200+3200:tile051.png
0.0143607:+1600+3200:tile052.png
0.0341039:+400+2800:tile043.png
0.0349564:+800+3200:tile050.png
0.0359226:+800+0:tile002.png
0.0549334:+800+400:tile008.png
0.0556793:+400+3200:tile049.png
0.0589632:+400+0:tile001.png
0.0649078:+1200+0:tile003.png
0.10811:+1200+400:tile009.png
0.116287:+2000+3200:tile053.png
0.120092:+800+800:tile014.png
0.12454:+0+2800:tile042.png
0.125963:+1600+0:tile004.png
0.128795:+800+1200:tile020.png
0.133506:+0+400:tile006.png
0.139894:+1600+400:tile010.png
0.143205:+2000+2800:tile047.png
0.144552:+400+2400:tile037.png
0.153143:+0+0:tile000.png
0.154167:+400+400:tile007.png
0.173786:+0+2400:tile036.png
0.17545:+400+1600:tile025.png
0.193964:+2000+400:tile011.png
0.209993:+0+3200:tile048.png
0.211954:+1200+800:tile015.png
0.215337:+400+2000:tile031.png
0.218159:+800+1600:tile026.png
0.230095:+2000+1200:tile023.png
0.237791:+2000+0:tile005.png
0.239336:+2000+1600:tile029.png
0.24275:+800+2400:tile038.png
0.244751:+0+2000:tile030.png
0.254958:+800+2000:tile032.png
0.271722:+2000+2000:tile035.png
0.275329:+0+1600:tile024.png
0.278992:+2000+800:tile017.png
0.282241:+400+1200:tile019.png
0.285228:+1200+1200:tile021.png
0.290524:+400+800:tile013.png
0.320734:+0+800:tile012.png
0.330168:+1600+2000:tile034.png
0.360795:+1200+2000:tile033.png
0.391519:+0+1200:tile018.png
0.421396:+1200+1600:tile027.png
0.421421:+2000+2400:tile041.png
0.421696:+1600+2400:tile040.png
0.486866:+1600+1600:tile028.png
0.489479:+1600+800:tile016.png
0.611449:+1600+1200:tile022.png
0.674079:+1200+2400:tile039.png
```

and, hey presto, the last one listed (i.e. the one with the highest entropy)  `tile039.png` is this one.

[image]

I have drawn a rectangle around its location using this command

```
convert image.png -stroke red -fill none -strokewidth 3 -draw "rectangle 1200,2400 1600,2800" a.jpg
```

[image]

I concede there may be luck involved, but I only have one image to test my mad theories. You may need to tile twice, the second time with an x-offset and y-offset of half a tile width, so that you don't cut the QR code and split it across 2 tiles. You may need different size tiles for different size barcodes. You may need to consider the last 3-5 tiles located for your next algorithm. But I think it could form the basis of a method.

Comment: But I need where qr code can be, and the size can be different.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59611541/1.pdf
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59611541/3.pdf
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59611541/4.pdf

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Very nice approach! You could "perfectionize" it by discovering also cases where your sectionizing the complete page leads to also splitting the QR code so it is not contained completely in one tile, but spread over 2 or even 4 tiles.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Thank you. I probably could do as you say, but I suspect you are going to produce a much simpler, more accurate, pixel-perfect method in a couple of minutes anyway :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I wish I could, but no time at the moment. It's an interesting problem to solve though :)  (Also, I've seen you  updated your answer with hinting at the problem of accidentally splitting the QR code area. That hint is "good enough" for me :)

Comment: It's not working, when size or placement are different

Comment: Please have another look - like I said, you may need to play around with the tile sizes, and guesstimate some things about your documents, like Kurt was suggesting in his comment/question underneath your original question.

Comment: See updated answer incorporating improved initial extraction of images from PDF rather than having ImageMagick render them as new images.